# Erro ao fazer deploy de uma aplicação java com postgres

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat

Caros.

Criei uma pequena aplicação web usando postgres. Porém, quando executo do eclipse, ela roda sem problemas. Mas quando exporto o ficheiro .war e tento fazer deploy no servidor tomcat, ela me retorna o erro abaixo:

> ```
> Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to build entity manager factory
>     at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:83)
>     at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:54)
>     at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
>     at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:96)
>     at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
>     ... 45 more
> Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling Driver#connect
>     at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:132)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator$1$1.convert(BasicConnectionCreator.java:118)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.convertSqlException(BasicConnectionCreator.java:140)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:58)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:75)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:106)
>     at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
>     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
>     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:260)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:94)
>     at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
>     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
>     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
>     at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1887)
>     at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1845)
>     at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:857)
>     at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)
>     at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:425)
>     at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:849)
>     at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:75)
>     ... 51 more
> Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
>     at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:292)
>     at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
>     at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:195)
>     at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:454)
>     at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:256)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:55)
>     ... 68 more
> Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
>     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
>     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
>     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
>     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
>     at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
>     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
>     at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:70)
>     at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:91)
>     at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:192)
>     ... 73 more
> ```

O banco de dados está ligado. Fui ao ficheiro conf/server.xml do tomcat para alterar o timout e ficou da seguinte forma

Nota: Executo no eclipse com sucesso e imediatamente exporto o .war e quando tento fazer deploy retorna o erro. Algum outro ponto posso configurar o timout?

Comment: @JoãoMartins Veja isso: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5359/132

Comment: A causa do seu problema é `connect timed out`. Isso sugere que a sua aplicação não está conseguindo conectar no banco de dados. Tem certeza que o problema realmente foi estar rodando dentro do war ao invés de algo mais bobo do tipo que quando você foi rodar dentro do war, o banco de dados estava desligado?